# How to combine multiple tables via model with AREL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, union, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a legacy database that I need in order to pull data for a rails app.

Each table is split up into
multiple tables with a numeric suffix. Each table holds data for
four hours of the day.

We have the "widget_status" table.  This table does not actually hold data.

The existing tables are:

1. widget_status_0
2. widget_status_1
3. widget_status_2
4. widget_status_3
5. widget_status_4
6. widget_status_53

Each table holds four hours of data.

This query works:

```
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_0  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod )  
 UNION 
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_1  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod )  
 UNION 
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_2  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod )  
 UNION 
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_3  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod )  
 UNION 
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_4  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod )  
 UNION 
( SELECT timestamp, some_field FROM widget_status_5  
 WHERE widget_sn = \@widgetsn and timestamp > $timePeriod ) LIMIT 200
```

I'm trying to create a rails model "widget" that will query the six underlying tables using a `union` or  something similar, so the rest of the code will ignore trying to deal with six tables.

I have multiple tables that follow this pattern and want to be able to abstract out the handling of the 6 tables so in te rest of the code I can just use find etc as per normal.
Can anyone suggest how this can be done using AREL?  Or any way at all that is nice and simple?

Comment: do you need read and write, or just read ? because if your RDBMS allows it, you can use [database views as tables with active record](http://books.google.fr/books?id=thTju-4duY4C&lpg=PP1&ots=nFmsRSwKu0&dq=enterprise+rails&pg=PA147&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), but it is only reliable in readonly mode, and requires some fiddling around (beware, given link is outdated).

Comment: I only need read but can't create views as I don't have access to do that.

Comment: ... do you need to instantiate widgets, too ? if not, i'd say - just stick to the sql. If you want, you can do it with arel ( there's a union test in the select manager test that you can find in the source, it provides a good example of how it works ), but i'm not sure it would add value to your sql query. Don't forget the low-level methods like `select_all`, either

Comment: Hi,  I am hoping to just be able to do Widget.find_by_some_value(3) or Widgit.order(xx).limit(xx).find_by_value etc.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly an answer : unfortunately, i'm not sure how you could use AR to do this kind of stuff unless you have the ability to create a DB view (as you mentioned in the comments).

Without a DB view, you will lose a lot of AR's magic, including query methods and auto-instantiation of objects.

However, arel can help you to build queries (note : what follows is not tested, you might have to tweak it, but you get the spirit).

```
class WidgetStatus    

  # when given a block, this method will apply the same arel chain 
  # to all tables and union them.
  def self.build_query 
    (0..5).map do |i| 
      arel_chain = Arel::Table.new("widget_status_#{i}") 
      arel_chain = yield arel_chain if block_given?
      arel_chain
    end.inject(){|chain, next| chain.union next }
  end

end
```

now you can do arel stuff like :

```
query = WidgetStatus.build_query do |table| 
  table
    .project( :timestamp, :some_field )
    .where( 
      table[:widget_sn].eq( @sn )
      .and( table[:timestamp].get( @t ) 
     )
end
```

and use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all query` to get useful data.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  It almost works :(.

I don't understand the guts of AREL enough to know quite what is going wrong here but it appears that you can not chain union calls.  The call to union returns an Arel::Nodes::Union object.

This object doesn't have a union method.
  
base.rb:33:in `build_query': undefined method `union' for #<Arel::Nodes::Union:0x007f894704db48> (NoMethodError)

So in the inject, the first time it is called works, the second fails.

        The testcase notes:
        # FIXME this probably shouldn't return a node

Comment: No worries.  I can do that.  Thanks much for your help.